# Mat-menu incorrectly calculating its render position

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

**What are you trying to do?**

Render a menu item `below` of a button

**What are you seeing that does not match your expectations?**

The menu item shifting its position to `above`, if its height > current view port height.
Expected: The menu should render below

**Reproduction**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dsccj4

**Steps to reproduce:**

Click on the button. The menu (yPos shift its position to above, even though parent has enough space to accommodate .

Environment
Angular: 8
CDK/Material:8
Browser(s):Chrome
Operating System : MacOs

Comment: In your stackblitz, I am seeing the menu is rendered just below of the button (as expected). I am not seeing any issue.

Comment: to display below, there must be enough space for the div and it's padding. ref: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1EH7.png

Comment: This is the expected behavior. The ````mat-menu```` will display below until it can fit between the button and bottom of the viewport, after which it will shift above. If this did not happen, the menu would render outside the viewport making content unreadable.

Comment: @user2216584 https://ibb.co/qykP8Ry

Comment: @BinsonEldhose this is also expected behavior. As mentioned by nash11 , menu will be rendered within viewport

Comment: @user2216584 thanks for the reply, is there any way to push or expand the viewport while displaying the menu